# Migrating from http to https

Tags: redirect

I am migrating my WordPress (**http**) website  on another (**https**) server  on a **subdomain**.

I have done what is usual when you migrate a website:

- Download the files via ftp
- Exporting the database and replace the addresses (e.g replace `http://example.com` with `https://subdomain.examplexyz.com`)
- Create the Database    on the new server
- Import files (via FTP) and database
- fix `.htacces` and the wp-option table

without any results

It happens that as soon I search for the **subdomain** `https://subdomain.examplexyz.com` I am redirect to `https://examplexyz.com`, so on the new server but not on the subdomain where I moved the website.

Now i have to questions:

1) When I export the Database do I need to replace the `http://example.com` with `https://subdomain.examplexyz.com` ?

2) Should I change something in .htacces?

Comment: 1. Yes, do that, you're probably redirected because still your home and site url options are pointing to the old domain.

Answer (score 2):

Other answer to this question is the direct way to corrupt database if it contains links in serialized data (and most of modern themes do this).

WordPress keeps all internal links as absolute. (If your main page contains link to let say contacts page, in database it is stored as http://example.com/contacts.php). If such a links are used in buttons of theme, they will be inside of serialized data and direct replacement in database will corrupt your site.

What you need is to use special tools like [Search and Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) or even better, excellent plugin for moving sites - [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

These tools will help you to move your site correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is there something specific you need to do to avoid corrupting the data with search and replace?  Why wouldn't it also replace the serialised data?

Comment: Nothing specific. Search and Replace tool, as well as Duplicator plugin, correctly process all serialized data and replace links in them. It is not a direct text replace, it is conversion of serialized data into php objects, replacing text in objects fields, and serializing back to the database. That is why it works.

Comment: Hmm, that's not the solution then.  My database grew by 10 times when I replaced http:// to https://.  It still seems to work though.  I'm trying to work out what happened.

Comment: Those instruments I mentioned are **the only** right solution to be used for migration. And used them countless times.

Answer (score 0):

You can also search you database for the URL to see if there's anything you missed: and then replaced it with the new URL (https://subdomain.examplexyz.com)

`SELECT * FROM wordpress.wp_options where option_value LIKE "%example.com%";`